# Reusing leaflet map elements in custom functions in Shiny/R

Tags: r, leaflet, web-mapping, function, shiny

I have an application that reuses several leaflet elements, so I'm trying to build functions to streamline my code.

All of my logical attempts failed, so I utilized an example I was familiar with [here](https://uasnap.shinyapps.io/ex_leaflet/). I copied the format and created functions for markers and polygons, seen in the example below:

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)


markerFunction <- function(map, x, y){
  addCircleMarkers(
    map, x, y, 
    color = "red"
  )
}

polygonFunction <- function(map, polygon){
  addPolygons(
    map, polygon, 
    color = "red"
  )
}

# shinyapp 
shinyApp(
  # ui
  ui = fixedPage(
    # leaflet output 
    leafletOutput("map", height = 600)
  ),  # END UI

  # server
  server = function(input, output, session){

    # map output 
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        addTiles
    })  # END RENDER LEAFLET 

    # map proxy
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")

    # observe
    observe({
      proxy %>% 
        markerFunction(40, 50) %>% 
        polygonFunction(gadmCHE)
    })
  }  # END SERVER 
)
```

The marker function works fine, but the polygon function spits the error:

> Warning: Error in derivePolygons: addPolygons must be called with both
>   lng and lat, or with neither.

which is the error I get when I don't include `data =` explicitly. When I add `data = polygon` to the function definition and `data = gadmCHE` to the polygonFunction() call, I get the error:

> Warning: Error in polygonFunction: unused argument (data = gadmCHE)

Running the markerFunction() on its own yields the expected result, but I'm perplexed how it works without including the `map` argument. When I remove it from the function, it no longer works.

I've tried many configurations and can't get any of them to work except for the markerFunction() as it exists in the above example app. I have tried including and excluding the `map` argument, explicitly defining other arguments (like x, y, and data) in both the function definition and function calls, excluding the explicit arguments with no luck. I want to create similar functions for polygons as well, but haven't found a solution.

Comment: I think you simply need `data = polygon` in your polygonFunction. Or you could use `mapview::addFeatures` instead which is feature type agnostic so should also work in the markerFunction.

Comment: @TimSalabim sorry, I guess I wasn't clear. I did add `data = polygon` to the function and it still didn't work. I tried including it in the function definition but not the function call and vice versa, including it in both, and excluding it from both...no luck!

Comment: For me the code runs fine when I add `data = polygon` only in the function definition.

Comment: @TimSalabim oh, it works when I also include the `map` argument! Now to try my more complex example...on that note, do you have any insight why the `map` argument is necessary when it's never called in the function?

Comment: It is called inherently in the pipe. The piping operator basically assumes that whatever is passed on from the previous call is used as the first argument in the subsequent call, in this case the `map` argument. Moreover you need to match your functions arguments to those of `addPolygons` which expects a `map` argument at first position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TimSalabim pointed out, the following function definition and call work (in their respective places):

```
polygonFunction <- function(map, polygon){
  addPolygons(
    map, data = polygon, 
    color = "red"
  )
} 


polygonFunction(gadmCHE)
```